# Find all posibililties in a dict (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following dict in python:

```
{main1: {x: 1, y: 2}, main2: {a: 1, b: 2}}
```

The result I need is all possible combinations, something like:

```
{main1: {x: 1}}
{main1: {y: 2}}
{main1: {x: 1, y:2}}
{main2: {a: 1}}
{main1: {x: 1}, main2: {a: 1}}
{main1: {y: 2}, main2: {a: 1}}
{main1: {x: 1, y:2}, main2: {a: 1}}
...
```

etc. I feel there is some pythonic solution, but I can't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
itertools.combinations()
```

might help you.
You can call it, getting combinations of size 1, 2 and so on in basic cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools
[zip(x,main2) for x in itertools.combinations(main1,len(main2))]
```